# Get Route Parameter from URL in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

How can I get the value of `access_token` in my `ng-controller` as `$routeParams` from the following URL?

```
http://www.example.com/#/access_token=asdfjaksjdhflanblasdfkjahdloahds
```

Comment: Ought to go through https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route. You need to specify this in route and in angularjs it will be more so like `/#access_token/asdafdgdhfghfgh`

Comment: but I get the url as /#key=value format, not /#key/:value

Answer (score 3):

on you app config

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/:id', {
    ....
    controller: 'DetailsController'
  }).
```

use on your controller $routeParams

```
.controller("DetailsController", ['$routeParams',function($routeParams){    
    var id = $routeParams.id; // this name is from config :id
}]);
```

Comment: but I get the url as /#key=value format, not /#key/:value

Comment: @TahinRahman key=value is equivalent to key:value. They're just two different conventions for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

If it isn't defined explicitly in your route, then it will not be available in the `$routeParams`

If your route is defined as:

```
.when('/access_token/:token')
```

Then you will be able to access it like this:

```
var token = $routeParams.token;
```

However, the URL you have defined isn't really a good route param, or a valid query string parameter. If it were a valid query string parameter

```
#/?access_token=blahblahblah
```

Then you could access it via the `$location.search()` method.

```
var accessToken = $location.search('access_token');
```

As it stands right now, you would still have to parse out the value if the entire key/value pair resides in your route param.