# Comparing $location.path() to route with params not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have an app where I must allow non logged in users to access some pages, such as forget password form, registration etc.

```
  if(!Authentication.isLoggedIn()){
    if($location.path() === '/thanks'){
      // Allow
    } else {
      // Redirect to login
      $location.path('/login');
    }
  }
```

I am using ngRoute and I have a route with a param in it (/lostpassword/:token) but I can't find a way to compare it properly to allow it the same way I can for /thanks

So to clarify, I am not looking for the value of :token, I just want to be able to tell when the route /lostpassword/:token is being viewed.

I am really new to angular and I'm hoping it is just a small syntax issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want the value of your token?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26100981/3103677

Comment: I don't need the value of token, I just need to know when that route is about to be accessed, so I can choose to allow or block the user from viewing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to know if the url contains a keyword you can do:

```
var path = $location.path();
if (path.split('/').indexOf('some') > -1){
    // do something
}
```

[Angular $location docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path)

**EDIT**

You can also use [angular router](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) which can get a url template. this is the preferred way to handle routes within you application.

Comment: This answer did help me get further, but I am a bit worried that if I had another route that contained the keyword, then I might be giving public access on a page I don't want to. But if there is no other way I will accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: What are the differences between the routes? (btw I have updated the answer)